# How to use QueryWrapper.select(columns) in Custom SQL statements in mybatis-plus?

Tags: sql, mybatis

This is my wrapper.

```
QueryWrapper<Tag> tagQueryWrapper = Wrappers.<Tag>query()
                .select("name", "count(*) num")
                .groupBy("name")
                .orderByDesc("num");
```

This is my mapper.

```
@Component
public interface TagMapper extends BaseMapper<Tag> {

    @Select("select * from tag left join blog_tag bt on tag.id = bt.tag_id ${ew.customSqlSegment}")
    List<Tag> selectNameNum(IPage<Tag> page, @Param(Constants.WRAPPER) Wrapper<Tag> queryWrapper);

}
```

I don't know why this 'select(column...)' **doesn't work**.
The SQL statements it generates are as follows:

### `select * from tag left join blog_tag bt on tag.id = bt.tag_id GROUP BY name ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT ?,?`

---

**please help me, I want to know how to replace the '*' in the SQL statement with select(column...)**

Comment: anybody else? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `Constants.WRAPPER` is `ew` you can use another getter in `Wrapper` to get the select columns list (similar to how you get `customSqlSegment` already) like this:

```
@Component
public interface TagMapper extends BaseMapper<Tag> {

    @Select("select ${ew.sqlSelect} from tag left join blog_tag bt on tag.id = bt.tag_id ${ew.customSqlSegment}")
    List<Tag> selectNameNum(IPage<Tag> page, @Param(Constants.WRAPPER) Wrapper<Tag> queryWrapper);

}
```